# Strange "error" trying to connect to my server from iOS devices

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an app which connects to my server to fetch scores, register users etc - the usual stuff.

If I run it on the simulator, it works fine.

If I run it on the device using xcode it works fine, and continues to work fine even once I disconnect the device from xcode and use the app directly from the phones desktop.

However when I build an .ipa file and use that, the app does not connect to my server - it just timeouts. 
Does anyone have an idea about what could be causing a difference between how it works on the phone when it was put there directly via an xcode build + run, and when it is dropped on as an .ipa using organizer/iTunes?

As far as I am concerned they should be exactly the same, so I have no idea about where to even start looking.

I am building with the dev target as iOS3.2, using xcode4.2 and iOS sdk5.0. Have tried it out on a 3GS and iPod Touch 4th gen both with the same result.

If any more info is needed then I can give that, but fundamentally everything works, so I suspect that maybe there is a permissions error or a file I need to include that I'm not aware of. This project was originally designed by someone else and they are no longer around, other projects I have made connected to my server without any issues so I'm really hoping someone can help.

Comment: What happens if you build it to your iOS device using XCode, then disconnect it from the USB and try to run it? Does it work? If not, try sharing your computers connection over wifi and connect. If it still doesn't work, try filtering the traffic using e.g. Wireshark and see what the iOS device tries to connect to.

Comment: If I run it in xcode, and then disconnect - the app works exactly as it should. Even if I shut it down while running in the background and restart it, the app still works. It's only when running from a 'separate' build that it doesn't work, which is obviously the most important version as that's what I'll be submitting to Apple :-(

Comment: Of course, that what I wanted to isolate. Have you tried re-archiving after cleaning the project? Also, try using [Testflightapp.com](http://Testflightapp.com), a really good service that makes ad-hoc release way easier.

Comment: Funny you should say that, I've just started using Testflight this weekend, seems like a very useful tool. Just going to try cleaning and then archiving immediately to see if that helps, although I have been cleaning the project semi-regularly already. Fingers crossed...

Comment: I find "doing it manually" quite a hassle, so thats why I use testflightapp. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: No luck - the new build still fails to connect to my server. I'm going to go through the project again and see if there is anything which would prevent the device connecting while on a device - just don't see why it DOES work on the device when built directly from xcode. Surely it treats it as iOS and not Mac OS X even when running this way.

Comment: Even using testflightapp? Try do do a dumb debug, when connecting, show an UIAlertView with the URL you are going to open. Just to see its correct. If not, try opening the URL in safari.

Comment: Well, yes. If you are using the app on wifi on a network with a local server and faulty setup DMZ. but then I would never work, even after XCode build. Test the URL in safari and see if it works, safari on your device that is. Without XCode or anything else connected... same scenario.

Comment: Turns out I'm a moron. While I had put the correct address down for the server - it was only correct for debug builds. Release builds had a typo, and I was so sure I'd checked it already. Thanks for your help anyhow, I'll be sure to vote all of your comments, also if you'd like to put something along the lines of "have you checked the server address is correct as it's case sensitive" as an answer then I'll mark it as correct (I can't do it myself for a few hours so I'd rather you got something for your time). Plus I'd prefer the question had some kind of answer for those stuck in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my last comment above, the error was simply down to release builds attempting to look for an incorrect server address.